# join two tables in CI

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables poolRequests and users
poolRequests containg columns-> fromId(userId),toId(userId),requestType(1/2)
users containg columns-> userId, name

Now I need to join these two tables like

```
select users.id ,users.name from users
if requestType=1
join poolRequests on users.userId= poolRequests.fromId  
if requestType=2
join poolRequests on users.userId= poolRequests.toId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select users.id ,users.name
from users
join poolRequests
on (requestType = 1 and users.userId= poolRequests.fromId)  
or (requestType = 2 and users.userId= poolRequests.toId)
```